# how to use long-tail keywords in my blog posts?

Tags: seo, wordpress, keywords, blog, yoast

I'm using wordpress for my blogging and yoast plugin for seo. recently i read a tutorial about "long-tail keyword" usage. but i get confused when i want to use them in my blog posts. take this long-tail keyword:

- best gaming mouse and keyboard for ps4

Imaging i want to use this as my **primary keyword**(focus keyword) in my blog post. how should i use it in post title and other parts of my article?
-should i use it in the exact same order in my title or post?
-how to use it in yoast keyphrase input? should i use exact match of the focus keyphrase in the input?

as you know Google is capable of recognizing the separate words from longer search terms, even if the words are not in the exact same order as the query.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rank for that specific phrase - I would say yes - use it in the exact same order in your title and post. You will also want to use it the exact same way in yoast. Make sure you add it to your alt tags in your images as well. Finally, and possibly most importantly, I would use it as your URL - that exact phrase.

As far as how to use it - try things like: Are you looking for the best gaming mouse and keyboard for ps4? Where to find the best gaming mouse and keyboard for ps4? In my opinion these are best gaming mouse and keyboard for ps4...

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, in order to rank your focus keyphrase in a short time, you have to write it in your post title, description, heading, url possibly.But you don't have to overwrite it, for example, repeating keyword, and repeating key element words.
In my experience, your focus keyphrase is somewhat long.
So, you may divide it to two keyphrases, i.e.best gaming mouse for ps4, best gaming keyboard for ps4.
Good luck!